# Bounds on function from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $\phi : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be continues and differentiable on $( a,b)$ and let $\lVert x\rVert = \sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$ the euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^m$, show that $\lVert\phi(b)-\phi(a)\rVert \leq \sup_{t \in (a,b)} \lVert\phi'(t)\rVert (b-a)$ ?

I did used Lagrange mean value theorem on $g(t) = \langle\phi(t),\phi(b)-\phi(a)\rangle$ but ended up with two sup on the interval $(a,b)$

Any hints or proof or ideas are appreciated

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think this is an application of Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: @IAmNoOne i think so, but i used it twice so my bound is weaker than what i have to show!

Comment: Use MVT for the function $t \to \phi (at+(1-t)b)$ defined on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just to apply the Mean Value Theorem to your function
$$
g(t) := \langle \phi(t), \phi(b) - \phi(a)\rangle,
\qquad t \in [a,b].
$$
Namely,
$$
g(b) - g(a) = \|\phi(b) - \phi(a)\|^2,
$$
whereas, for $t\in (a,b)$, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get
$$
g'(t) = \langle \phi'(t), \phi(b) - \phi(a)\rangle
\leq \|\phi'(t)\|\, \|\phi(b)-\phi(a)\|
\leq \sup_{s\in (a,b)}\|\phi'(s)\|\, \|\phi(b) - \phi(a)\|.
$$
On the other hand, by the MVT, there exists $\xi \in (a,b)$ such that
$$
g(b) - g(a) = g'(\xi) (b-a)
$$
so that
$$
\|\phi(b) - \phi(a)\|^2 = g'(\xi) (b-a)
\leq \sup\|\phi'(t)\|\, \|\phi(b) - \phi(a)\|\, (b-a).
$$

Comment: you used Cauchy-Schwartz inequality ?

Comment: Yes, in the third formula.